# Questions with simple syntax errors

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, question-quality

The following question is asking ["How to specify multiple conditions in an if statement in JavaScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript).

```js
if (Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) !! (Type == 2 && PageCount == '') {
    PageCount= document.getElementById('<%=hfPageCount.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

I would have thought this question would be closed since a compiler will let you know you have a `SyntaxError` and fixing it is trivial.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!!'

Is there value in keeping questions like this?

Comment: Is this a problem that happens often? If so, then it would be a good idea to have a canonical question like this on SO. If it's some random typo that happened because the author wasn't careful then there's probably no future value in such question.

Comment: It took 10 years to find 116 users that found it useful. I can see how many new to that &^%$# language will make that mistake and googling the error probably returns that question. You have close votes. Use them. Who know what happens.

Comment: I was mostly curious because I have tried to answer questions with syntax errors and they were closed as typos before I posted my answer. 

Comment: It is never too late to cast close votes. Start today.

Comment: @rene This applies to most languages, it has nothing to do with the &^%$# language it was tagged with  I wanted to ask before casting a vote. Is that discouraged?

Comment: This question suffered from edits; it lost the opening bracket `{` in rev2 and then had a code typo corrected (`!!`-> `||`) in rev5... I updated the question to revert both of these back to the original state. Neither should have been changed, whether the question deserves to be closed or not.

Comment: The votes on the post in question aren't a recent phenomenon; [the rep graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWYB6.png) is pretty gradual over time (at least after the first few years where it sat below 20, [SEDE link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210232/graph-of-post-score-over-time?PostId=8710442#graph)).

Comment: i find the question and answer perfect for  Q&A side,

Comment: None of the 2012 - 2018 answers mention the gist of it, using "`!!`" instead of "`||`".

Comment: (The canonical for `!!` in JavaScript is *[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)*.)

Answer (score 20):

#### For how-to questions, the asker's attempt only exists to help describe the goal

The question is asking "How to specify multiple conditions in an if statement in JavaScript".  If you aren't familiar with JavaScript's if syntax, you don't care how someone else did it.  You just care about the answer.

Further, there can be other ways to accomplish that goal: look at the various answers that give ways to do so with completely different syntax.

#### Misunderstandings are not typos

Not understanding how nesting conditionals works isn't a typo.  They clearly don't understand that.  A typo is something you meant to do, but accidentally failed to do.  The "typo" reason is for questions unlikely to help others in the future.  Based on the voting, this has clearly been useful to many people.

Comment: All of that said, some of these answers are of ...questionable quality and relevance to the question asked.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with it being useful to "many" people here.  I think the sentiment is that this is one of those older questions that snowballed because it was *so* dang easy to answer because it's a mistyping of nested conditionals, since literally all you need is an additional set of parentheses on the outside of the expression to make it work.  Any JavaScript tutorial back in 2012 could have pointed you to the right answer and shown you what you needed to do.  There are other things that good answers would've recognized, like factoring `Type2` out, but...

Comment: ... *everyone* that answered this went for the easy points of "oh, let's just put parens around the expression and answer the OP's question.  If a question gets ***this*** many duplicate answers, it really starts to smell like it's a typo.

Comment: "For how-to questions, the asker's attempt only exists to help describe the goal" - this is a common cause of frustration for me. People **very often** say "how do I actually do X?" when they **clearly* mean "why does my attempt to do X fail in manner Y?" - i.e. they are looking very specifically for debugging help. If the question *really is intended* to be about how to specify multiple conditions, I would expect it to be phrased that way - showing examples of code with single conditions, and then asking how to make the code run only if [either/both] conditions are met.

Comment: As asked, the question *would have been* useful to close duplicates from people who have the same misunderstanding (some other languages wouldn't require enclosing parentheses for the entire expression, and the error message doesn't do a good job of pointing at the intended fix - someone might infer that `||` should be `or`, like it is in Python, for example). The question should have been properly disambiguated when it was asked.

Comment: It seems like we have a lot of cases of "the problem was caused by a typo, but people ignored the typo in order to talk about solutions for the underlying task", such as this one. But we **also** have a lot of cases of "OP was asking about the underlying task, but posted an example with a typo (possibly not present in the actual code) that lots of people fixated on". Like that JSON question from the other day. Possibly other variations on the theme.

Comment: I agree on this answer. I think that a typo can be if he is putting a `cnsole.log()` or something like that, not this particular case. Now, if you are looking into a broader question that SOMEWHERE in it has `!!` instead of `||` then you might consider that a typo. But I think it is very unlikely that someone posts a code without even checking for a syntax error IF THEY KNOW about the syntax. In fact, this user probably knows that `!!` causes a syntax error, it's just that they don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because of questions which I was answering but were closed calling it a typo. They're clearly not a typo but were closed because the answer was so simple and it was because of a few missing/misplaced characters

Comment: If the question arises due to a misunderstanding then it's answerable (or we close it as a dupe). If we can't tell whether it's a simple typo or a misunderstanding we *have* to ask the OP, and if they don't clarify we can close as Needs Details.

Comment: "Misunderstandings are not typos" but *egregious* misunderstandings are usually. Whether this is such a case is debatable. It is definitely a basic syntax mistake, but on the other hand many people make the same mistake.