# Why are typos not mentioned in the list of questions that shouldn't be answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, help-center, typographical-error

Within my first week or so of joining SO I posted an answer to a question where the only issue with the code was that they forgot to add `()` for a method call or something similar. I think I even used the word typo in my answer.

Within 15 minutes or so another user commented on my answer telling me not to answer questions that were caused by a typo in the code. Upon asking for a reason, they explained that questions caused by a typo do nothing for the site or any future users looking for solutions to their own problems, and that because I had received an upvote it meant that even though the question was eventually closed, it would remain on the site because the upvote means that someone found it useful making it harder to delete. They added that the comment section was perfect for such occasions. I have no idea how accurate that explanation is, but it seemed to make sense to me so I have refrained from doing this since.

Since then I have seen many others make the same suggestions to other users making the same mistakes, and I myself have made similar suggestions since.  I also discovered when I was able to cast close votes, that there is a specific option regarding typos among the reasons for casting the vote.

My first question is, is this policy of users not posting answers to questions that are caused by typos an official policy/strategy/guideline/rule/convention?

If so then why is this not mentioned on the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page?  Is it mentioned elsewhere that I can point to people who have answered questions that were obviously caused by a typo and where the user exclusively addresses the typo only as their answer?

Towards the bottom of the How to ask page there is this section:
[image]

No mention of typos though.

My question is solely regarding people posting answers to questions caused by typos.  Not the questions themselves the people answering them.

Comment: Because that page is universal, the same on all SE sites, and non-editable by mods. Fortunately, that page also links to "[defined in the help center (/on-topic)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" which is editable by mods and already mentioned questions that are non-reproducible and/or due to typos.

Comment: @AndrewT.  I read that page as well.  That page is written for the context of the asker.  That isn't helpful since the people asking the questions with typos clearly are not doing it intentionally.

Comment: The main point is that off-topic questions shouldn't be answered, and the community has decided that [typo questions are off-topic since 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252585/2821954).

Comment: @AndrewT.  that addresses my question... thank you.  It is still seems to be written in the context of the asker but it least it makes a direct link between typos and one of the items listed in the questions that shouldn't be answered section.

Comment: @AndrewT. even older than that, it's been like that from [before the MSO/MSE split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/are-we-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @RobertLongson I believe it.  But it isn't an obvious rule for new users.  Someone new to the site is only thinking about answering the question and getting reputation.    That is why I think it would be beneficial for it to explicitly included in a list of questions that shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Some have difficulties with the language some type in their mobile and autocorrection does its work, both are no ground not to answer

Comment: @nbk so you are the first person to disagree... you think that they should be answered?  Everyone else thinks that the comment section is adequate enough myself included

Comment: @Alexander "New users" do not get a get out of jail free card just because they are new, quite the opposite really. People who are new should double down on learning and reading how the site works. That personal responsibility is the same in all facets of life. It is more that people are used to being able to get away with just doing as they please on the internet, and then they are faced with the harsh reality that on Stack Overflow it has consequences.

Comment: @Gimby  I don't understand your comment.   I wasjust asking if it is an official policy/rule, and why it seems there isn't a better way of communicating the rule?  now that you mention it though, are their negative consequences to answering these types of questions?

Comment: @Alexander downvotes, naturally. I posted that comment because your own comments have a tendency to reason from a perspective of leniency towards new users, as if they are allowed to be ignorant. Not true, for anyone. All people have a lot of reading to do before they can effectively participate on this site. And so should naturally stumble upon the phenomenon of a typo question, it's not exactly like the topic never comes up.

Comment: @Alexander i am known here on meta, to have his own opinion and defend them, i correct and get corrected a lot. So yes i think answer it, correct the misspelling and go on with your live, you have doen a good work

Comment: An egregious side effect of the _"typo"_ close reason, is that it can be abusively used to close questions. Here is an example of a mod (!!!) stomping on a valid question that clearly didn't meet the close criteria _"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"_. When challenged on the closure, their (absurd) justification was citing the accompanying verbiage _"While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers"_. See the comments under the question [Java - OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space](Java - OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space)

Comment: So apart from any other issues, the wording for the _"typo"_ close reason doesn't bear scrutiny. Just claim that _"this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers"_ and by dark magic you have a flimsy pretext to close a question, even when it _is_ reproducible and _does not_ contain a typo!

Comment: Ooops - I fudged the link above. See the comments under this question: [Java - OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72282566/2985643). To be clear, the mod closed the question, but it was later reopened. Also worth noting that an answer to the question received six upvotes, so it is hard to argue that the question wasn't useful.

Comment: I think that whether a typo-based question should be closed or not is subjective. Take [my question and self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058233/php-compile-error-cannot-use-empty-array-elements-in-arrays) for example, which is clearly resolved as being due to a typo (caused by an extra comma in an array) but has been useful to hundreds of people (based on upvotes; maybe thousands based on page views).

Comment: Another current question on what qualifies as a typo: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419635/4014959

Comment: @MosheKatz I don't think it's *totally* subjective, though. OTOH, some typos are quite common, especially for newcomers to the language (eg `if(a=b)` in a C program) and deserve a decent answer that can be used as a dupe target. However, in many cases, unless there's a clear error message it would be rather unlikely for someone with a problem caused by a typo to find a matching typo, and even if they do stumble across one in their searches they may not recognise that it's similar to their problem.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384463/are-questions-about-code-published-in-a-book-exclusions-from-the-general-off-top) decided that typos in off-site (and offline) resources aren't off topic. So "no typos" is not a blanket rule.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  That actually seems to make the most sense, and that this is simply a popular opinion/ and frequently given suggestion.

Comment: @skomisa If the code in question has a typo and no other obvious reason for any issue then VTC is correct. OP is more than welcome to edit the post into better shape, i.e. fix typos, and if they can still reproduce the issue vote to reopen the question with corrected code and any new details. This is how the question gets to the "...even when it is reproducible and does not contain a typo!" part of your comment.

Comment: @DrewReese But the entire point of my comment was that for the question I linked to there was no typo, and the problem was reproducible, yet a mod force closed the question for that (bogus) reason. It's no wonder new posters don't feel welcome on SO when they receive that treatment.

Comment: @skomisa I see. I think I sort of agree with the Mod's line of reasoning on that one. It's not an interesting question in the longterm since the answer is basically, "don't allocate more memory than you have resources for" or "get more physical resources so you stop running out of it". It's not reproducible in the sense that we don't have the OP's physical device to know the resource limitations.

Comment: Why can't that simply be posted as an answer though? There are plenty of questions about the Fibonacci series on SO, and there was every reason to believe that the OP had no idea what the actual problem was at all. The notion that questions are fair game for closure because we can't replicate their memory limitations is just nonsense. That same disingenuous reasoning might be applied to perfectly valid questions about (say) network performance performance problems, or issues with a web site. A helpful solution could have been provided without even needing a similar environment to the OP.

Comment: @AndrewT. you write _"...that page is universal, the same on all SE sites..."_ .  Are you sure?  The bit about a question being _"...not about programming as defined in the help center..."_ would seem quite site-specific to me.  I don't see any reason why one more site-specific sentence couldn't be added.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes, it's universal. They're using a template though, so "not about `{topic}` as defined in the help center" is filled automatically based on each site's parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is that questions that are ultimately resolved by correcting a typo should be quickly answered and then quickly closed and ignored.

Answering it does the most good to the person asking the question (who usually doesn't realise that's what the problem is, so ruling typo questions out-of-scope won't stop them being posted). Answering in the comments is not what comments are for; the features you can use in writing a comment are **by design** not suitable for pointing out where exactly the typo is and how it should be corrected in all but the most trivial of cases.

After that the question/answer are unlikely to be of any use to other readers in other times, so the most good we can do for them is to make them unlikely to be shown the question when they were looking for something else.

I can't recall *ever* reaching a closed typo-question from Google or from SO's search when I was looking for something else, so I don't personally care much if they are actually deleted. But many of the commenters here seem to think this is a serious problem and are concerned that answering such questions interferes with a function that automatically deletes closed posts with no answers from cleaning up these useless typo questions. My view would be that a policy to avoid answering such questions in order to have the existing auto-delete heuristics clean up better is working for our tools instead of having our tools work for us; if the heuristics aren't doing what we want we should change the heuristics!

Comment: So your saying answer the questions, and hopefully SO will update it's automatic removal  features?

Comment: @Alexander Precisely. Well, more precisely I'm saying that *I don't care* whether SO updates its automatic removal features. But I believe the people who do care and want these kinds of questions to be deleted would be better served by SO updating its auto-cleanup heuristics than by trying to convince every single member of the community to go along with a policy of not answering these questions.

Answer (score -10):

I think a typo *may* be mentioned in comments, but if it is posted as an answer it is really easier to verify as a "typo question".

Personally, I think it is no big deal if it is closed after answering. The answer will just be indicating such a typo (which you even can't describe when immediately closing as a typo question).

Comment: The problem with answered closed questions is that they are harder to delete (might not be automatically deleted) and then just litter the page.

Comment: @gre_gor Litter which page? The list of recently asked questions? Those will quickly age off the page as soon as people stop editing or answering the question.

Comment: I mean the whole page. They can still show up in google searches. Usually the question is completely unrelated to the actual problem (typo).

Comment: answering OP's question - it's by design that if question is well asked, it may be answered  no matter of it's being typo or duplicate or whatever

Comment: @Kos that's only true until it's been closed as a typo or duplicate.  No answers are accepted after that.

Comment: @MarkRansom well.. yeah, *closed* question can't be answered I guess

Comment: @gre_gor Read my answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419676/6699433). The close reason for typo clearly says that it is a close reason that is used *after* the question has been resolved.

Comment: Maybe the algorithm around when a question is automatically deleted needs work.  If a question is closed, that implies that its answers shouldn't really be there, and should definitely not change what happens to the question after closure.